# How can I add the geolocations to my web app

Tags: html, geolocation

I have a project which can users share their locations in their posts or profile 
 like facebook, twitter or Instagram.

how can I add these places and locations to my app?

Comment: You want to know how to get the user's location? Is this what you're searching? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Get their location via `geoip` -- And store it in a database of your choice.  What have you attempted?

Comment: thank you guys i will try geolocation

Comment: What did you try so far? the question is to general

Comment: I just started to code share module and before that I hadn't tried anything so far about share location

Comment: I read about geolocation after comments and answer. I think  what i need is html5 geolocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at HTML5 Geolocation API? That and reverse geocoding using the Google Maps API you should be all set:

Geolocation Reference:

[W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

[GoogleDevs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)